# Future Builder is Not Building

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to log a user in with the boolean value assigned to the 'isVerified' field in the user's firestore document.

**In other words, If 'isVerified' is true then continue, else return to verify page.**

I put in debugPrint statements to help me catch the error and it appears that the Future Builder is not getting past the builder context.  I have read other documentation to regarding future builders but I can't find where I'm going wrong, please let me know if there's anything I can clarify.  Thank you

**Using Future Builder for async**

```
FutureBuilder (
        future: getVerified(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) { <--------- Nothing past this line is running
          debugPrint('>> Home: FutureBuilder: checkpoint'); // does not print to console
          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
            debugPrint('>> Home: FutureBuilder: Snapshot has data and no error');
          }
          return const Text('');
        }
      );
```

**Future**

```
Future<bool> getVerified() async {
  debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified Started');
  User? user = auth.currentUser;
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    bool isVerified = value.data()!['isVerified'];
    debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified $isVerified'); // this variable is currently true or false
    return isVerified; // this will return Instance of '_Future'
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using stateful widget above future builder, and what type of verification are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change `FutureBuilder` it is good. And I recode your `getVerified()` function.

Can you try

```dart
Future<bool> getVerified() async {
  debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified Started');
  bool isVerified = false; // set your response to false

  // get your user
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  // check the data from firestore if the user is not null
  if (user != null) {
    final docSnapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();

    if (docSnapShot.exists) {
      isVerified = docSnapShot.data()!['isVerified'];
    }
  }

  debugPrint(
      '>> Home: getVerified $isVerified'); // this variable is currently true or false
  return isVerified; // this will return Instance of '_Future'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).where('your filed', isEqualTo: 1).get();

Comment: I think your login process will work properly with getx state management without StreamBuilder.

Comment: So I don’t need a collection reference just that one declaration?

Comment: Error: Expected a value of type 'bool' but got one of type '_Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>>'

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Future<bool> getVerified() async {
   debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified Started');
   User? user = auth.currentUser;
  if(user != null) {
  final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .get();

   bool isVerified = value.data()!['isVerified'];
   return isVerified;
  } else {
 return false;
 }
}
```

don't use promises in `future` method use `async await`

Comment: I am able to get the variable from the database, if I were to run a normal call it would return as an instance variable.  I need the boolean value inside of the future builder, but it’s not building correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you are using function that returns bool value, FutureBuilder future cannot able to get the data. Try to donot use bool.

```
Future<bool> getVerified() async {
      debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified Started');
      User? user = auth.currentUser;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        bool isVerified = value.data()!['isVerified'];
        debugPrint('>> Home: getVerified $isVerified'); // this variable is currently true or false
        return isVerified; // this will return Instance of '_Future'
      });
      return false;
    }
```